# React Builds- Which files go on the server? Why isn't my project deploying?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, web-deployment

**Goal:** I have created the start of a React project and wish to test it on my server (hosted by goDaddy, uploading via cPanel). My app works fine in Development Mode.

**Question:** I have ran npm build which has created a build folder, but what files am I supposed to upload to my server? I tried putting the entire contents of the build folder on, but it still says the site is not launched. Is this because there is no index.html file generated? Currently my build folder contains: assets.json, LICENSE.txt, package.json, server.js, yarn.lock, chunks/ and public/. Is there supposed to be an html file generated? Or should these files be sufficient to deploy the website given that it works in development mode?

Thanks for bearing with me, this is the first time I have tried to deploy a React App and likely have several fundamental misunderstandings of how it works. Also if anyone is willing to chat for several minutes so I can ask a few questions about my project and react let me know - much appreciated!

Comment: You'll need files under `/public`. Isn't there an `index.html` already?

Comment: They are under /public_html, and the html file there already is just to display the page that says "Future home of something quite cool.
If you're the site owner, log in to launch this site

If you are a visitor, check back soon." Adding my files here had no effect

Comment: That's related to goDaddy and how they handle `index.html`. You might wanna consult with them. A question with `react` tag doesn't get you that far here.

Comment: So the files generated in npm run build under the build folder are all I need? If that is true I will take it up with goDaddy

Comment: Yes. That's usually all you need if your website is fully client-side. By the way, you can use more modern services like `netlify` or `now.sh` for that matter. goDaddy is now goGrandpa.

Comment: I called goDaddy and the tech support said I need to create an index file that points to the start of my app because I am not providing an index file with my build folder. Is this true?

Comment: If you see an `index.html` then you have it. You just need to figure out where on goDaddy you need to put that. Probably `/public_html`.

Comment: I do not have an index.html file in my build folder. The only index file is the default one on the server that lasts until you replace it with your project

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: No- I used a React Template on WebStorm and run "npm run build" to create my static build folder. I am unfamiliar with create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

## Hello

Dear,
If you can try to change your package.json file and add ("homepage": "http://yourDomain/",) like this

```
 "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "yourDominUrl",
```

Like

```
  "homepage": "http://yourDomain/",
```

and

build again

```
npm run build
```

and the build folder is only should be uploaded file

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is much more simple than appears:  Just run npm run build, then just upload that whole folder to your GODADDY server. Importantly, you *must* place your index.html (or app-name.html) directly on the / public path defined by your URL's DNS.  So, Top-level has your single entry point index.html that points to folder build/ to get your xyx.main.js  and the xyz.main.css ...
and that's it! easy as pie